# Macbook Pro boot options wont work, corrupted hard drive?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My macbook pro was running really slow, so I restarted the computer. Now it wont start up at all, I get the flashing file with a question mark. I also tried a bunch of the boot options like holding down "option" while booting, etc. All I get is a mouse cursor on a plain white screen. I don't have anything plugged in to the computer so that's not the problem.

Does this mean I have a corrupted hard drive? Would there be a way to save the data on the hard drive? I'm not sure what OS it has and I don't know how to look it up without it actually booting up.

Comment: Try booting the system up with the recovery cd. See what happens.

Comment: It's important to list the startup key combinations you've tried--that will help narrow down what might be going wrong.